# 1997 Dodge Ram 1500 Stereo Wires Different

Tags: audio

My Aftermarket Stereo Doesn't match the colors of my truck. I don't have the Yellow or black wires like as the aftermarket radio has it.

Comment: I am sure you have a question hiding somewhere in there. You'll need to edit this post to make it more clear to use.

Answer (score 2):

Wire colours don't have to match, wire functions need to match. Some car munfacturers have the function of wires printed on the wires themselves, or on the top or back of the original stereo. Match the function of the wires.